# preg_match optimization - regex is too slow

Tags: php, regex, optimization, preg-replace

`(.[^\n]*?)\[code](.*?)\[\/code](.[^\n]*?)(*SKIP)(*F)|(.[^\n]*?)\[php](.*?)\[\/php](.[^\n]*?)(*SKIP)(*F)|some_rules_here`

The pattern above makes the function work too slow.

With it:
http://regex101.com/r/qP4tT5/1
Page gets loaded in more than 3 seconds.
Regex debugger says it took 5153 steps in total to execute the regex.

Without it:
http://regex101.com/r/fG4tW0/1
Page gets loaded in only 0,3 seconds
Regex debugger says it took only 4 steps to execute the regex.

Why do I have to use it:
Because if the emoticon's shortcut is inside a `[code]` or `[php]` tag, it shouldn't be HTMLed.

Is there an alternative method which does the same thing faster?

Comment: You should specify what the "thing" you want to do is exactly. With sample input and output.

Comment: `[code]` and `[php]`? Emoticons? Are you parsing BBCode from forum posts? BBCode is an irregular language (like HTML), and we all know what happens when you [try to parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). I think you need a BBCode parser (which can be blindingly fast).

Comment: @DarthAndroid @jeroen My question is clear enough. I have a BBCode and Emoticon parser(made using preg_replace and preg_match functions) which is developed by myself. It works perfectly without any errors. The only problem is its speed. If a BBCode or an emoticon is inside a `[code]` or `[php]` tag, the parser doesn't replace it and skips it as what it should do. But like I said before, it is too slow.

Comment: `[code]:([code]:([/code]:([/code]` Should all of these smilies be skipped?

Comment: @Wellenbrecher Then you cannot use regular expressions to build a pseudoparser that achieves that for arbitrary input. You need a proper BBCode parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this regular expression a bit.

```
~\[(code|php)][^[]*\[/\1](*SKIP)(*F)|:\(~i
```

[image]

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qP4tT5/8)

Comment: This is just what I need! Thank you. But it didn't work well in php. I think the `[/\1]` part causes the problem. The \ character escapes `1` and gives error. And when I escape the slash like `[/\\1]`, it says "unknown modifier '\' ". How can I fix this?

Comment: @Wellenbrecher Use `$1` instead then.

Comment: No it does not handle nesting. OPs original regex does not either.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I didn't see you used ~ instead of /. My parser is working faster now. The page gets loaded only in 0,1 seconds. It was taking 0,3 seconds before. Thank you again!